# JRuby 9k is not working with Puma and torquebox 4

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, puma, torquebox

My application is running perfectly fine with jruby-1.7.12 with puma and torquebox 4.

And I am trying latest jruby-graal(9k) with puma and torquebox 4.

But my server is not getting started with jruby-graal. This is where it's getting stuck.

```
krunal@krunal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-U530-Touch:~/code/test$ rails s puma 
file:/home/krunal/.rvm/rubies/jruby-graal/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:27 warning: ambiguous Java methods found, using isJavaIdentifierStart(int)
file:/home/krunal/.rvm/rubies/jruby-graal/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:28 warning: ambiguous Java methods found, using isJavaIdentifierPart(int)
file:/home/krunal/.rvm/rubies/jruby-graal/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:27 warning: ambiguous Java methods found, using isJavaIdentifierStart(int)
file:/home/krunal/.rvm/rubies/jruby-graal/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:28 warning: ambiguous Java methods found, using isJavaIdentifierPart(int)
```